# OpaqueType::get() function in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I am following the code from the project
https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/java/trunk/lib/Compiler/Resolver.cpp that uses `OpaqueType::get()` and it used to be in `llvm/IR/DerivedType.h`, but it's been removed now. What should I use instead.

Also, my code https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/java/trunk/tools/class2llvm/class2llvm.cpp included one header file `#include <llvm/Bytecode/WriteBytecodePass.h>`
which has also changed.

Please tell me what I should use in replacement of these.

Comment: What version of LLVM were you using and to which did you upgrade to? Can you please amend your question with that information?

Comment: @compor, I am using llvm -6.0.1 version

Comment: please amend the question, not the comments. Also, please add what was the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

Well, opaque types disappeared more than 7 years ago in LLVM 3.0. As a replacement – you should use just empty StructType. Bytecode disappeared in LLVM 2.0 which was released more than 11 years ago. Everything is "bitcode" now and there are plenty examples within LLVM codebase how to use the corresponding API. E.g. almost any tool inside "tools" subdir has such code. See "tools/opt/opt.cpp" as an example.

The code that you're trying to "upgrade" is 12 years old, unmaintained and always was of proof-of-concept quality.

Comment: @ Anton Korbeynikov, I got about StructType, but how do I change my code with it. I mean what I have to first create StructType::`create(LLVMContext& Context)` and then use `StructType::get()` or something else, Please suggest me how do I use StructType in here